# Who wants a hat? Come and get your hats (2015 edition)!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

'Tis the season! [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) is back on participating Stack Exchange sites in full effect, from **14 December 2015** until **3 January 2016**.

For those of us who haven't seen it on other SE sites, as this would be the first for Expats.SE, Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can "wear":

[image]

Sites vote explicitly to participate, and if the idea is welcomed by site's users, it will be enabled in the aforementioned period. It's important to know that even if Winter Bash is enabled, users can explicitly opt out if they want to (there will be "I hate hats" option on their profile page which will revert the site to its familiar look for the user).

So, it's time to decide if we want hats on our Expats.SE! **Vote** on the answers below **until 08 December 2015**. We'll enable hats only if there's sufficient support for it (for some yet undetermined value of "sufficient"). Please don't downvote an option, rather upvote only the one you choose. Of course, comment as necessary.

Your mod friends at Expats.SE remind you to enjoy hats responsibly.

Comment: beat me to it! hell yes :)

Comment: Finally, it's hat season again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of the poll closing the vote is 6 to 1 with an additional conditional yes. We be safe to immigrate to colder climates this year.

Answer (score 8):

### YES!

Bring on the hats, can't ever get enough hats.

An up vote is for warm ears. Do not down vote.

Answer (score 1):

### No!

I'm a firm believer in bare heads.

An up vote is a vote for bare heads. Do not down vote.

Answer (score 1):

## Conditional YES/NO!

Some major jurisdictions declare Christmas Day as a public holiday on January 7th, 2016, and Chinese New Year is February 8th, 2016.

A winter bash that ends on January 3rd, 2016 (by the Gregorian calendar) just does not cut it.

Let's participate ***only if*** all expatriates can have an equal footing.  Do not down vote.